# Исправьте речевые ошибки. Объяснить

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я попытался наиболее лучше ответить на вопрос.

Отсюда открывается панорама на Москву-реку.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что домашнее задание

Answer (score 2):

В первом предложении применено несовметимое словосочетание "*наиболее лучше*" (за превосходной степенью одного наречия следует сравнительная степень другого). Правильное здесь выражение превосходной степени: "**как можно лучше**" или "**наилучшим образом**". Формально правильно, но стилистически неудачно было бы "*наиболее хорошо*", хотя с другим смыслом вполне можно сказать "*наиболее полно*".

Во втором предложении "панорама" не сочетается с падежом следующего существительного. Правильно "**панорама** Москва(ы)-рек**и**", по аналогии с "фотографией" (панорама - своего рода воображаемая рамка, ограничивающая поле зрения). Либо можно сказать "**вид на** Москва(у)-рек**у**".

Comment: Вообще говоря, панорама это совсем не фотография. Это именно вид. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0&all=x

Comment: Первоначально понятие было введено в живописи - это "препарированный" вид. Возможно, отсюда и закрепившиеся падежи: понимание в  значении природного вида появилось позже.

Comment: Понимаете, меня это сейчас не очень интересует. Вы некий тезис **в ответе написали**, который неверен. Ну так скажем: **противоречит словарю**. Это недоразумение никак не снять комментариями.

Comment: В каком из словарей рекомендуется "панорама на что-то"? В моём ответе дано пояснение, как обходиться с падежом - да, как и в случае фотографии, это "панорама чего". Вторичность определения панорамы как вида местности, можно увидеть напр. в словаре Даля. Но даже в определении панорамы через "вид на" нельзя механически заменить слово "вид" на "панорама", не трогая падежа: это будет грамматической ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Первое предложение ужасное во всех смыслах. Надо так: «Я попытался лучше ответить на вопрос». Слово *наиболее* здесь вообще ни к чему, оно используется при образовании аналитической сравнительной степени.

Во втором предложении всё чуть-чуть сложнее (для меня). Возможно, нужно написать так: «Открывается панорама Москвы-реки».

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: открывается панорама моря/с видом на море.

Comment: А чем плохо исходное?

Comment: behemothus, в словарях без предлога.

Comment: Вы это каждому спросившему намерены объяснять?

Comment: Вот я тоже не понимаю, в чем у вас проблема. )))  Неужели так трудно написать подробно, если вы так в том уверены. Я, например, сильно в том сомневаюсь.

Comment: Это и плохо, что я не понимаю Вас, когда читаю Ваши ответы. И ладно бы только я...

Comment: Вот только не надо говорить за других. Вы сейчас поставили минус просто так. Вам это доставляет удовольствие пакостить другим  и не только мне!). Просто вам нравится признавать  себя умнее других и считать свои ответы самыми правильными. И еще: просьба не отвечайте на этот комментарий и на никогда(!!!) не комментируйте мои ответы!

Answer (score 0):

Я попытался максимально хорошо / как можно лучше ответить на вопрос.

Отсюда открывается панорама Москвы-реки / вид на Москву-реку.

Comment: Да, но вопросы настолько просты, что заставляют думать, что автор вашими руками домашнее задание делает.